# JSON and javascript

Tags: javascript, json

hello i have a response in json that looks like that

```
{
    "el": {
        "reviewed_percentage": "0%",
        "completed": "16%",
        "untranslated_words": 8,
        "last_commiter": "zaabalonso",
        "reviewed": 0,
        "translated_entities": 1,
        "translated_words": 1,
        "last_update": "2012-07-06 13:08:10",
        "untranslated_entities": 5
    },
    "en": {
        "reviewed_percentage": "0%",
        "completed": "100%",
        "untranslated_words": 0,
        "last_commiter": "zaabalonso",
        "reviewed": 0,
        "translated_entities": 6,
        "translated_words": 9,
        "last_update": "2012-07-06 12:28:48",
        "untranslated_entities": 0
    },
    "gl_ES": {
        "reviewed_percentage": "0%",
        "completed": "33%",
        "untranslated_words": 7,
        "last_commiter": "zaabalonso",
        "reviewed": 0,
        "translated_entities": 2,
        "translated_words": 2,
        "last_update": "2012-07-06 13:06:46",
        "untranslated_entities": 4
    }
}
```

how can i convert it like that using javascript

```
[{
            "language"="el",
            "reviewed_percentage": "0%",
            "completed": "16%",
            "untranslated_words": 8,
            "last_commiter": "zaabalonso",
            "reviewed": 0,
            "translated_entities": 1,
            "translated_words": 1,
            "last_update": "2012-07-06 13:08:10",
            "untranslated_entities": 5},
........etc.
]
```

Comment: JSON is just a javascript data structure in text format. Conver it to native JS data, then treat it like you would any other array/object.

Comment: ok i'll make it an object and then how am i going to access elements object["el"].completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the JSON data and create a new set of data with the format you desire, such as using the pseudo code below (assuming oldJSON is assigned as the JSON response as posted)

```
var newData = [];
for ( var s in oldJSON )
{
    var data = oldJSON[s];
    data.language = s;
    newData.push(data);
}
```